# Execute sql task result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to count number of rows

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count
FROM table
group by col1,col2
```

and assign this to result set in execute sql task but am getting an error

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "numberofrowstoerror": "Single Row result set is specified, but no rows were returned.".

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that is actually assigning the variable.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Too many rows to fit in a regular integer?

Comment: When you run the query in your target database, what do you get?  It sounds like the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, how do you have your Result Set (Result Name / Variable Name) defined?  What is the datatype of the variable?  SSIS has a tendency to not easily show the actual error without digging into it.

Comment: How is your Execut SQL Task defined. Main page, Parameters and Result Set tab

Comment: i have result set which is set to a variable int data type and my table is empty for now it is error log table

Comment: But how is your Execute SQL Task defined? How have you configured it. We do not know if you have specified the wrong values in one of the 10+ input fields on the `General` tab, whether you have specified *anything* on the `Parameter Mapping`, `Result Set` or `Expressions` tab

Comment: i get one value and one result set mapping mapped the count to variable in result set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that this has helped me with this problem in the past in "Execute SQL Task". If an SQL Task Editor expects results returned in a row … but there are no records to return then the following SQL fills a null return with a space. Note : can also be used to return zero if a numeric “return row” is expected

```
SELECT '' + ISNULL ((SELECT field FROM table WHERE (key = ?)), '') AS field
```

Comment: Thank you for this it helped me to get some idea on what am doing i got solution from your answer